# Acro Package Bug with Kerning

Tags: luatex, typography, kerning, acro

I've observed that the `acro` package bugs out the kerning. It makes the kerning pair apply incorrectly after the acronym. In my MWE, the second word in each pair has incorrect kerning. I've added an image to make the horizontal offset more clear. `acro` is generally otherwise a useful package. I'm unsure how to fix this.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stix2}
\usepackage{acro}
\DeclareAcronym{pow}{
    long={Prisoner of War}
    ,short={POW\@}
}
\DeclareAcronym{top}{
    long={Totally Okay Puddle}%made-up acronym
    ,short={TOP\@}
}
\begin{document}
POW\@.
\par
\acs{pow}.
\par
TOP\@.
\par
\acs{top}.
\par
POW\@,
\par
\acs{pow},
\par
TOP\@,
\par
\acs{top},
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

The explanation is simpler with this test file

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stix2}
\usepackage{acro}
\DeclareAcronym{pow}{
  long={Prisoner of War},
  short={POW},
}

\begin{document}

POW.

\acs{pow}.

\showoutput

\end{document}
```

In the log file or the console you see

```
....\T1/stix2/m/n/10 P
....\T1/stix2/m/n/10 O
....\kern-0.3
....\T1/stix2/m/n/10 W
....\kern-1.00002
....\T1/stix2/m/n/10 .
```

for the first line and

```
....\T1/stix2/m/n/10 P
....\T1/stix2/m/n/10 O
....\kern-0.3
....\T1/stix2/m/n/10 W
....\write1{\token_to_str:N \ACRO {recordpage}{pow}{\int_use:N \g_shipout_totalpages_int \ETC.}
....\T1/stix2/m/n/10 .
```

for the second line.

Clearly, the `\write` instruction makes the kerning unfeasible.

One might argue that `\write1` (which means write to the `.aux` file) should be issued before the acronym, but the author of `acro` seems not to agree. File an issue report.